# Webpack | jQuery UI => relative image urls for icon set are not being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, webpack, loader, webpacker

This error :

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/admin.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png' in '/Users/trip/Sites/the_website/app/javascript/packs'
```

Stems from this code snippet within jQuery UI

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```

Now this can be solved, by me manually copying and moving a copy of these files to the entrypoint of my webpack. **The issue I believe is that Webpacker is not telling the CSS file where the `public_output_path` is**

My Webpack Config :

```
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(css|less|scss|sass)$/i,
      include: /node_modules/,      
      exclude: [
        /\.module\.(css|less)$/,
        /\.(config|variables|overrides)$/ 
      ],
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {loader: 'css-loader'},
        {loader: 'postcss-loader'},
        {loader: 'resolve-url-loader'},
        {loader: 'less-loader'},
        {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {implementation: require('sass')}},
      ],
    },
...
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i,
      use: [{
        loader:  'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: isProduction ? '[name]-[hash].[ext]' : '[name].[ext]'
        },
      }],
    }, {
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'jquery-ui'   : 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui',
```

And then it is called here from **Admin.scss** :

```
@import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
```

Would anyone have *any* idea what I am possibly doing wrong here? Anything to perhaps look into? All comments/questions/haikus welcome :)

Comment: What version are you using? If it's `v5`, then [`file-loader` is deprecated](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/). If that doesn't work, could you maybe replicate the issue in a repo?

Comment: @AndreiGătej oh great find, thanks. I'm on webpack `5.11.0`. So I'll start there at least.

Comment: @AndreiGătej I made a minimalist replicated repo here. ReadMe has steps to reproduce. https://github.com/gotoAndBliss/webpacker-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question doesn't have an answer, and I basically had the same problem, I'll share what worked for me when using Webpack 5 and jquery-ui 1.12.1.

In my case, a jquery-ui dialog was popping up, but the close icon in the top-right was missing, the button icons were missing, and the buttons were not styled.

I had some jquery-ui imports in my root webpack entry named `base.js`:

```
import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete"; // !! [1]
import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable"; // !! [1]
import "jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-highlight"; // !! [1]
```

jquery-ui version 1.12.1 doesn't come with a /dist/ folder and I needed this specific version because of another script. Long story short.

Since I needed dialog, I added to `base.js`:

```
... stuff above +
import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog";
```

This did not work in my case because I was instantiating the jquery-ui dialog on a button click event:

**mydialog.js**

```
  trackNotesButton.addEventListener("click", showNotesDialog);

  function showNotesDialog(e) {
    ...
    $(dialog).dialog({
      title: "Notes",
      closeOnEscape: false,
      ...
```

[image: dialog example]

### The Solution (for me)

I removed the import from `base.js` entry and imported the jquery-ui dialog widget in the file where `$(dialog).dialog(...)` occurred.

**mydialog.js**

```
import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog"; // <-- this was the key!

trackNotesButton.addEventListener("click", showNotesDialog);

function showNotesDialog(e) {
  ...
  $(dialog).dialog({
    title: "Notes",
    closeOnEscape: false,
    ...
```

This may sound super-obvious to most, but I thought importing the dialog into the root entry point would have been enough. Maybe it is necessary for events that don't fire immediately.

[image: dialog with icons]